# How to build GRPC with custom BoringSSL symbol prefix?

Tags: c++, cmake, grpc, boringssl

I need to use in the my application both GRPC (which uses and comes with sources of the BoringSSL) and another third-party library which is tied to OpenSSL, and does not link with BorinSSL. Specifying both of them  on the linker arguments leads to some linker errors.

So I've got an idea to build gRPC with custom BoringSSL symbol prefix (and as result do not "shadow" OpenSSL), because I have seen in the standalone BorongSSL build instructions that there is a way to do that ( https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/HEAD/BUILDING.md#building-with-prefixed-symbols ), so I assume this is potentially possible in the GRPC build too.

I am using CMake (and cannot use Bazel). OS: Linux, Windows. Toolchains:  VS2017, GCC.

So I've tried to add `-DBORINGSSL_PREFIX_SYMBOLS=/path/to/symbols` and `-DBORINGSSL_PREFIX=my_bssl_prefix` on the GRPC cmake command line, but it has finally printed me a warning that these symbols were not used:

```
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    BORINGSSL_PREFIX
    BORINGSSL_PREFIX_SYMBOLS
```

If anybody knows, please explain, how to do that correctly.

Comment: Just build GRPC with additional option `-DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package`. So instead building BoringSSL and linking with it, GRPC will be linked with OpenSSL library which you already have.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting, But what "package" value should be? I just link with system-supplied openssl.

Comment: I was also thinking maybe I need to prefix those with gRPC_? i.e gRPC_BORINGSSL_xxxx?

Comment: "But what "package" value should be?" - The value should be **literally** `package`. See e.g. the comment at [CMakeLists.txt:68](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L68).

Comment: As for prefixes for BoringSSL symbols, I don't think this approach is the right one. Even if you will able to add the prefix for BorintSSL symbols, GRPC project still **expects** non-prefixed one.